# evidence slokas for 3 divisions of the universe

Tags: scripture, vedas

I'm looking for the evidence slokas that the whole universe in the brahmandara are divided 3 parts, upper world where devatas and pious people live, middle world: bhumandala, and underground world where the asuras live.

Comment: Basically they are three realms that is Space, Water and Earth which are ruled by Om(AUM) or Br(A)hma, Vishn(U) and (M)ahesh and occupied by Gods, Humans and animal/insects i.e. Triguna Maya of white Satva(wisdom) Saraswati,red Rajas(passion) Laxmi and black Tamas(ignorance) Kaali i.e trinity of old age, youth and childhood. https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/14 Geeta 14.5 O mighty-armed Arjun, the material energy consists of three guṇas (modes)—sattva (goodness), rajas (passion), and tamas (ignorance). These modes bind the eternal soul to the perishable body.

Comment: Gota 14.15 Those who die with predominance of sattva reach the pure abodes (which are free from rajas and tamas) of the learned. Those who die with prevalence of the mode of passion are born among people driven by work, while those dying in the mode of ignorance take birth in the animal kingdom. Those situated in the mode of goodness rise upward; those in the mode of passion stay in the middle; and those in the mode of ignorance go downward.

Comment: Dear Manu Kumar, Thank you for your kindly giving me the excellent teachings regarding to how tri-guna relating to all phenomena within the brahmandara.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hare Krishna

Vishnu Purana 3.7.1, 2, 3

श्री मैत्रेय उवाच
यथावतकथितं सर्वं यत्पृष्टो असि मया गुरो |
श्रोतुमिच्छाम्यहमं त्वेकं तद्भवान्प्रब्रवीतु मे ||1

सप्त द्वीपानि पातालविधयस्च  महामुने |
सप्तलोकाश्चयेअंत:स्था ब्रह्माण्डस्यास्य सर्वत :||2

स्थूलेै: सूक्ष्मैस्तथा सूक्ष्मसूक्षमतरैस्तथा |
स्थूलातस्थूलरैश्चैव सर्वं प्राणिभिराव्रतम || 3

Sri Maitreya Rishi said,
Oh Spiritual Master, whatever enquiries i have asked, you have answered them all as it is. Now kindly answer to the following question,  which i would like to hear.
Oh Great Sage, Inside this Brahmanda there are Seven dvipas, Seven Patalas, and Seven Lokas. In all these lokas the living entities are filled up in subtle, subtler, subtlest forms, also in gross, and grossier forms.

Comment: Dear Krsna prabhu, Thank you for your kindly teaching me.  Your answer is what I really want to know for solving my question(^o^)  I appreciate your mercy.

Answer (score 2):

This is vyahruthi mantra, bhoor, bhoova and swagha.. bhoor loka(7 worlds below earth bhoomandala including earth ) Bhoovar loka(space between swarga and earth) and swargha lokka(Other 7 worlds starting from heaven. The seven worlds are

Bhoo Loka Comprises
07  Bhu-loka
08  Atala-loka
09  Vitala-loka
10  Sutala-loka
11  Talatala-loka
12  Mahatala-loka
13  Rasatala-loka
14  Patala-loka

svarga Loka Comprises

01  Satya-loka
02  Tapa-loka
03  Jana-loka
04  Mahar-loka
05  Svar-loka

Reference
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loka

Comment: Dear Prasanna R, Thank you for your kindly teaching me three worlds within the brahmandara.I appreciate from my heart.